# Google Glass camera on Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, google-glass

I'm stuck on this for days I really don't know how to solve it I already tried the whole internet but no code seems to work to me.
What I wanna do is take a picture and send the image to my server.
The way I'm doing is this: I'm calling navigator.camera.getPicture method to take the picture and if no problems occur I send it to the server, but the callback for error is being called always even though the pictures is taken and storage on the device.
That's my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Camera</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.7.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            // Initialize the application
            app.initialize();

            // Listen for 'touchpad' events, which get registered as keydown events with keyCode 9 and 13
            document.addEventListener('keydown',keyController);

            // Wait for PhoneGap to load
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

            // PhoneGap is ready
            function onDeviceReady() {}

            // Called if something bad happens.
            function captureError(error) 
            {
                console.log("ERROOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOR");
            }

            function captureImage() 
            {
                navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoUriSuccess, captureError, { quality: 50, destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI });
            }

            function onPhotoUriSuccess(imageUriToUpload)
            {
                var url=encodeURI("http://ec2-54-186-34-253.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/upload.php");

                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileName = imageUriToUpload.substr(imageUriToUpload.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
                options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
                options.chunkedMode = true; //this is important to send both data and files

                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.upload(imageUriToUpload, url, function(success){console.log("sucess")}, function(error){console.log("error")}, options);

            }

            //Takes care of touch input
            function keyController(e)
            {
                // Show results in document body
                //document.body.innerHTML = e.keyCode;
                console.log("keyController");
                captureImage();
            }

            // Show results in document body
            function onError() 
            {    
                document.body.innerHTML = 'error';
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I forgot to post the error:

```
04-13 00:48:32.188: E/JHEAD(8586): can't open '/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.apache.cordova.example/cache/.Pic.jpg'
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/Android/data/org.apache.cordova.example/cache/.Pic.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at org.apache.cordova.FileHelper.getInputStreamFromUriString(FileHelper.java:101)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher.getScaledBitmap(CameraLauncher.java:582)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:335)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at org.apache.cordova.DroidGap.onActivityResult(DroidGap.java:864)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:4654)
04-13 00:48:32.195: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:2976)
04-13 00:48:32.203: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3023)
04-13 00:48:32.203: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-13 00:48:32.203: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1177)
04-13 00:48:32.203: W/System.err(8586):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-13 00:48:32.203: W/System.err(8586):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-13 00:48:32.211: W/System.err(8586):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-13 00:48:32.219: W/System.err(8586): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
04-13 00:48:32.227: W/System.err(8586):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
04-13 00:48:32.227: W/System.err(8586):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
04-13 00:48:32.234: W/System.err(8586):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
04-13 00:48:32.234: W/System.err(8586):     ... 19 more
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe ,You are missing `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` from your list of permissions. Without it the app will be unable to write the jpg file.

I had met the problem,I fund the answer from [Android Phonegap 2.2 Error compressing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13818313/android-phonegap-2-2-error-compressing-image)
good lucky